# PropertyGrid / PropertyDescriptor AddValueChanged EventHandler Overide

Tags: c#, overriding, propertygrid, eventhandler, propertydescriptor

I've been playing around with the Dynamic Type Description Framework for PropertyGrid (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415070/Dynamic-Type-Description-Framework-for-PropertyGri )

And have hit a slight road block with adding the event handler logic. Following the examples, when adding a new item, have assigned an EventHandler to "AddValueChanged"

```
// "OnPropCChanged" is hardcoded here.
Dyn.TypeDescriptor td = Dyn.TypeDescriptor.GetTypeDescriptor(propertyGrid1.SelectedObject);
Dyn.PropertyDescriptor pd = new Dyn.PropertyDescriptor(propertyGrid1.SelectedObject.GetType( ), "PropC", typeof(string), "Hello world",
pd.AddValueChanged(propertyGrid1.SelectedObject, new EventHandler(this.OnPropCChanged));
td.GetProperties( ).Add(pd);
```

And then the Event Handler:

```
private void OnPropCChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
// "PropC" is hardcoded here.
Dyn.PropertyDescriptor pd = Dyn.TypeDescriptor.GetTypeDescriptor(sender).GetProperties( ).Find("PropC", true) as Dyn.PropertyDescriptor;
string sNewValue = pd.GetValue(sender).ToString();
MessageBox.Show("New value is: " + sNewValue);
}
```

This all works fine, but requires multiple methods, one per item. What I would like to do is implement a global/override where the Label/Name of the edited item would be available; as I can't seem to get this via the object / EventArgs above.

At present, I have multiple methods, which simply call the changed method, like below:

```
private void FooChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    changed(sender, "Foo");
}

private void BarChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    changed(sender, "Bar");
}

private void changed( object sender, string change )
{
    switch(change)
    {
          case "Foo": break; // Do Foo actions
          case "Bar": break; // Do Bar actions
    }
}
```

I have been trying to implement something like below, but cannot figure out how to tie it all together / assign to the AddValueChanged event.

```
private void FooBarChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{
    string change = e.PropertyName.ToString();
    switch(change)
    {
          case "Foo": break; // Do Foo actions
          case "Bar": break; // Do Bar actions
    }
}
```

It appears I need to pass an EventHandler as per: PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)

Comment: You can make a method which accepts a `string propertyName` and `object sender` which does exactly what your top method does.

Comment: I've been trying that with the changed( object sender, string change ) method, but can't get that hooked in to the PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged

Comment: You can't, as its delegate signature is expecting `object sender, EventArgs e`. You'll need to create an "inner" method which is called from the delegate having the right signature. Does your event handler hold the property that changed?

Comment: Not from what I can see / gather. It jsut passes the object sender, and EventArgs e. I can't see to get any properties off eithr of them.